# How to get the image-URL from Media-Upload in a post?

Tags: images, jquery, custom-field, thickbox

I generated a new MetaBox for all standard posts in WordPress 3.1. There I generate a input:text field with the ID `_meta_fotos[pic]`, which should hould the image url generated by the standard media-uploader.
I want to use the standard media-uploader from the standard post window. So I generated the following JavaScript code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#_meta_fotos\\[pic\\]').focusin(function() {
    formfield = jQuery('#_meta_fotos\\[pic\\]').attr('name');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
  });
  window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    imgURL = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
    jQuery('#_meta_fotos\\[pic\\]').val(imgURL);
    tb_remove();
  }
});
```

On the first step all works fine. But I don't get the real image URL. All I get back is a URL to the correct uploads-path with a filename `blank.gif`.

I checked if the ThickBox is called by the `focusin`-function: It is alright.

I think the problem ist in the `send_to_editor`-function. It returns in `html` the code from the underlaying main-Page and not from the popup-window of the media-uploader/thickbox.

Can anyone help me, to find the mistake? Any help is aprreciated!

Comment: What are you getting back from the send to editor function, have a look at what's returned before you do anything with it... eg. `alert( html );`.

Comment: It's funny! If I alert `html` if see an empty alert-box. But if I use `var iFrame = jQuery('#TB_iframeContent', html); var iFrameDoc = iFrame[0].contentWindow.document;` and alert the `iFrameDoc` i get a html Object.

Comment: Posted an answer, hopefully you'll find the clues you need to solve the problem.. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly add an upload media button in a meta box field](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/properly-add-an-upload-media-button-in-a-meta-box-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate it to answer my own question.
But after hours of searching and trying I found a solution that works. I offer this solution, because it can't be interesting for others having the same problem. And for discussion, if there is a better way to get rid of the problem. Perhaps it is not very elegant, but it works ;-)

The peak is to change the `click`-event for the "Insert into Post"-Button in the ThickBox.

**edit**
Because the code worked only for ONE image in the library I had cto chnge the line in the `click`-function. Now it works with more then one picture

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //change click event for insert into post
  (function(){ 
var tb_show_temp = window.tb_show; 
window.tb_show = function() { 
  tb_show_temp.apply(null, arguments); 
  var iframe = jQuery('#TB_iframeContent');
  iframe.load(function() {
    var iframeDoc = iframe[0].contentWindow.document;
    var iframeJQuery = iframe[0].contentWindow.jQuery;
    var buttonContainer = iframeJQuery('td.savesend');
    if (buttonContainer) {
      var btnSubmit = jQuery('input:submit', buttonContainer);
      iframeJQuery(btnSubmit).click(function(){
        fldID = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace('send', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '');
        var imgurl = iframeJQuery('input[name="attachments\\['+fldID+'\\]\\[url\\]"]').val();
        jQuery('#_meta_fotos\\[pic\\]').val(imgurl);
        jQuery('#picPreview').attr('src', imgurl);
        tb_remove();
      });
    }
  });
   }
  })()
//open uploader
jQuery('#_meta_fotos\\[pic\\]').focusin(function() {
formfield = jQuery('#_meta_fotos\\[pic\\]').attr('name');
tb_show('Use pictures', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;tab=library&amp;TB_iframe=1');
return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar for a theme settings page i helped someone with, it looked a little different to what you have, but i'm going to post the code so you can compare.

**jQuery:**
Literally just the applicable parts taken from a working script i've used.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('img.font').click(function() {    
        form_field = $(this).next().next('input'); 
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?tab=type&from=t31os&post_id=0&TB_iframe=true');
        return false;
    })
    .hover(function() {
        $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    }); 

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        media_url = $(html).attr('href');
        tb_remove();
        $(form_field).val(media_url);
    }
});
```

In my case i had an image that trigeered the upload window, and passed back the value when the user clicked the **Insert into settings** field button(see below).

You'll notice that firstly there's a post ID passed in the media upload request, you should need this in order to see an **Insert into post** button in the window. Secondly there's an additional request parameter `from=t31os`, this allows me to selectively change the **Insert into Post** text, like so..

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_insert_into_post', null, 2 );
function change_insert_into_post( $translation, $original ) {
    if( !isset( $_REQUEST['from'] ) )
        return $translation;

    if( $_REQUEST['from'] == 't31os' && $original == 'Insert into Post' )
        return 'Insert into settings field';

    return $translation;
}
```

Hope that helps.

**Follow-up from comments:**
Here's some images of the provided code working inside my theme options page(the arrow is my image to trigger the uploader).

[image: The field]
The field.

[image: The uploader window]
The uploader window.

[image: The result]
The result.

You'll notice i didn't bother with the gettext filter, and that's simply because it's not integral to the code functionality(that's a personal touch and makes no difference here).

Have you correctly enqueued the necessary scripts? Namingly `media-upload` and `thickbox`, along with the thickbox stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for help, but... after playing with your code, I always get for `$(html).attr('href')` an undefined.

Comment: What are you clicking in the media window, are you using the "Insert into Post"(Insert into settings field) button? I've just used the above posted code inside my current theme(it wasn't there, but i've worked it in for testing) and it works perfectly for me(so you must be doing something different?).

Comment: In the library I'm using the "Insert into Post" button. But I think there is in WP3.1 a problem with the html-parameter. But I see the "Insert Into" Button always. The Bug from WP 3.0 is gone ;-)

Comment: I'm using 3.1 and testing the code, it works fine here, see screenshots added to answer.

Comment: Thanks for really good help. I found another idea in your Code (spliting between insert in textarea and field with additional parameter). But overall it didn't work.

Comment: I can only assume your usage is different in some way then, i can't reproduce the problem(s) described.