# Adding upload button in metabox

Tags: images, metabox, uploads

I want to add upload image button for the images and retrieve url.
Can someone pls help me, i have been trying this for quite a few days. I'm using code from this thread [Create more Meta Boxes as needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed).

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'dynamic_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamic_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function dynamic_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'dynamic_sectionid',
        __( 'Client Information', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'dynamic_inner_custom_box',
        'page');
}

/* Prints the box content */
function dynamic_inner_custom_box() {
    global $post;
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'dynamicMeta_noncename' );
    ?>
    <div id="meta_inner">
    <?php

    //get the saved meta as an arry
    $ourwork = get_post_meta($post->ID,'ourwork',true);

    $c = 0;
    if ( is_array( $ourwork ) ) {
        foreach( $ourwork as  $track ) {
            if ( isset( $track['thumb'] ) || isset( $track['client-img1'] ) || isset( $track['client-img2'] ) || isset( $track['client-img3'] ) || isset( $track['client-img4'] ) || isset( $track['client-desc'] ) ) {
                printf( '<p><strong>Thumb Image</strong> &nbsp;:&nbsp;<input type="button" name="ourwork[%1$s][thumb]" value="%2$s" size="50" /><br/><br/><strong>Client Image 1</strong> : <input type="button" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-img1]" value="%3$s" size="50" /><br/><br/>
                <strong>Client Image 2</strong> : <input type="button" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-img2]" value="%4$s" size="50"/><br/><br/>
                <strong>Client Image 3</strong> : <input type="button" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-img3]" value="%5$s" size="50" /><br/><br/>
                <strong>Client Image 4</strong> : <input type="button" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-img4]" value="%6$s" size="50" />
                <br/><br/>
                <strong>Client Link &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</strong> : <input type="text" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-link1]" value="%7$s" size="50" />
                <br/><br/>
                <strong>client Description</strong> :<br/><textarea id="elm1" class="tinymce_data" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-desc]" cols="75" rows="6" >%8$s</textarea><br/>
                <span class="remove">%9$s</span></p>', $c, $track['thumb'], $track['client-img1'], $track['client-img2'] , $track['client-img3'], $track['client-img4'], $track['client-link1'], $track['client-desc'],  __( '<span class="button">Remove Section</span>' ) );
                $c = $c +1;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
<span id="here"></span>
<span class="add"><?php _e('<span class="button">Add Section</span>'); ?></span>
<script>
    var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
        $(".add").click(function() {
            count = count + 1;

            $('#here').append('<p><strong>Thumb Image</strong> &nbsp;:&nbsp;<input type="button" name="ourwork['+count+'][thumb]" value="" size="50"/><br/><br/><strong>Client Image 1</strong> : <input type="type="button"" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-img1]" value="" size="50"/><br/><br/><strong>Client Image 2</strong> : <input type="button" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-img2]" value="" size="50"/><br/><br/><strong>Client Image 3</strong> : <input type="type="button"" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-img3]" value="" size="50"/><br/><br/><strong>Client Image 4</strong> : <input type="type="button"" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-img4]" value="" size="50"/><br/><br/><strong>Client Link &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</strong> : <input type="text" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-link1]" value="" size="50"/><br/><br/><strong>Client Description</strong> :<br/><textarea id="elm1" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-desc]" cols="75" rows="6"></textarea><br/><span class="remove"><span class="button">Remove Section</span></span></p>' );
            return false;       
        });
        $(".remove").live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
    </script>
</div><?php

}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function dynamic_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return $post_id;

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !isset( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'] ) )
        return;

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

    $ourwork = $_POST['ourwork'];

    update_post_meta($post_id,'ourwork',$ourwork);
}
```

Comment: I did a blog post about this, please check: [http://www.derby-web-design-agency.co.uk/blog-post/how-to-create-multiple-wordpress-3-5-media-uploaders-in-theme-options/27/](http://www.derby-web-design-agency.co.uk/blog-post/how-to-create-multiple-wordpress-3-5-media-uploaders-in-theme-options/27/) I think this is what you mean :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly add an upload media button in a meta box field](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/properly-add-an-upload-media-button-in-a-meta-box-field)

Answer (score 1):

this is how I do to create upload button in metabox:

### FILE: template_dir/functions.php

add this lines:

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom-js.js');

// Add the Meta Box  
function add_custom_meta_box() {  
    add_meta_box(  
        'custom_meta_box', // $id  
        'Custom Meta Box', // $title   
        'show_custom_meta_box', // $callback  
        'post', // $page  
        'normal', // $context  
        'high'); // $priority  
}  
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');  

// Field Array  
$prefix = 'custom_';  
$custom_meta_fields = array(
    array(  
        'name'  => 'Image',  
        'desc'  => 'A description for the field.',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'image',  
        'type'  => 'image'  
    )  
);


// The Callback  
function show_custom_meta_box() {  
global $custom_meta_fields, $post;  
// Use nonce for verification  
echo '';  

    // Begin the field table and loop  
    echo '';  
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {  
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post  
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);  
        // begin a table row with  
        echo ' 
                '.$field['label'].' 
                ';  
                switch($field['type']) {  
                    // case items will go here 
                        // image  
                        case 'image':  
                            $image = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/image.png';    
                            echo ''.$image.'';  
                            if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                            echo    ' 
                                        
 
                                             
                                             Remove Image 
                                            '.$field['desc'].'';  
                        break;  
                } //end switch  
        echo '';  
    } // end foreach  
    echo ''; // end table  
}

// Save the Data  
function save_custom_meta($post_id) {  
    global $custom_meta_fields;  

    // verify nonce  
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
        return $post_id;  
    // check autosave  
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
        return $post_id;  
    // check permissions  
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
            return $post_id;  
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
            return $post_id;  
    }  

    // loop through fields and save the data  
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {  
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
        if ($new && $new != $old) {  
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
        }  
    } // end foreach  
}  
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta');
```

### FILE: template_dir/js/custom-js.js

```
    jQuery(function(jQuery) {  

        jQuery('.custom_upload_image_button').click(function() {  
            formfield = jQuery(this).siblings('.custom_upload_image');  
            preview = jQuery(this).siblings('.custom_preview_image');  
            tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');  
            window.send_to_editor = function(html) {  
                imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');  
                classes = jQuery('img', html).attr('class');  
                id = classes.replace(/(.*?)wp-image-/, '');  
                formfield.val(imgurl);  //get image url and copy to field
                preview.attr('src', imgurl);  
                tb_remove();  
            }  
            return false;  
        });  

        jQuery('.custom_clear_image_button').click(function() {  
            var defaultImage = jQuery(this).parent().siblings('.custom_default_image').text();  
            jQuery(this).parent().siblings('.custom_upload_image').val('');  
            jQuery(this).parent().siblings('.custom_preview_image').attr('src', defaultImage);  
            return false;  
        });  

    });
```

If you want to add more types of fields you can learn more at: [Reusable Custom Meta Boxes Part 1: Intro and Basic Fields](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/)

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent framework for interacting with Metaboxes that's reasonably easy to use (well documented) and includes support for multiple metaboxes options including image/file uploads. It's on Github: [Custom Metaboxes and Fields (CMB)](https://github.com/webdevstudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress). If you were to use CMB, this would be one approach for implementing an upload field.

You would need to register the file upload metabox and add a call to the CMB `init.php` using the following code in your `functions.php` file:

```
function be_sample_metaboxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = '_cmb_'; // Prefix for all fields
    $meta_boxes['test_metabox'] = array(
        'id' => 'test_metabox',
        'title' => 'Test Metabox',
        'pages' => array('post'), // post type (e.g post, post etc.)
        'context' => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name' => __( 'Test Image', 'cmb' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Upload an image or enter a URL.', 'cmb' ),
                'id'   => $prefix . 'test_image',
                'type' => 'file',
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $meta_boxes;
}
add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'be_sample_metaboxes' );

// Initialize the metabox class
add_action( 'init', 'be_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes', 9999 );
function be_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes() {
    if ( !class_exists( 'cmb_Meta_Box' ) ) {
        require_once( './metabox/init.php' );
    }
}
```

The line `require_once( './metabox/init.php' );` in the second function assumes you've placed the files from the CMB Metabox in a folder within your theme directory called `metabox`. Then to call this option in your template (e.g. `single.php`) you could use the following function

```
$file = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_test_image', true );
```